# Remote access of PC does not work

Tags: mac, vnc

In order to be able to do some heavy computing for my work at the university, I have remote access to a powerful computer. I used to use a pc to connect to this computer and this worked out fine. However I now use a mac and have installed Chicken of the VNC, but it doesn't seem to work.

After I fill in the host, followed by a colon and the port number, I try to connect (I omit the password). Chicken of the VNC then indicates that it is connecting but then disappears and nothing happens. On my pc I would normally get a login screen where I could provide my username and password and connect.

Filling in the password in Chicken of the VNC results in the same.

I would be glad if someone could help me out, as I can not find a solution. Do I use the right tool or is it only for getting remote access to the mac I use it on?

Comment: When using your old PC did you use a VNC client or Remote Desktop to connect?

Comment: What if you press Cmd-K in Finder, and enter the same details there, starting with `vnc://`? Like `vnc://some-ip-address`?

Comment: What are the OS versions on your host and client machines?

Answer (score 2):

It definitely sounds like the computer that you were using is a Windows machine and that you were previously using Remote Desktop (RDP) to connect to it. You can still do this from the Mac, you just need to get an OS X RDP client. Microsoft provides an [RDP client for OS X](http://www.microsoft.com/mac/remote-desktop-client), which is bundled with Office 2011 and also available as a free download from that link. Download and install that tool and give it a try.